# Facebook JS SDK cannot redirect after share

Tags: javascript, redirect, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to make a post in facebook with JS SDK and after that, I want to redirect user to another url. Here is my code;

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId            : '123*********',
        autoLogAppEvents : true,
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v2.10',
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="shareBtn" class="btn btn-success clearfix">Share</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('shareBtn').onclick = function() {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            mobile_iframe: true,
            href:              ' URL_1 ',
            redirect_uri:      ' URL_2 ',
        }, function(response){});
    }
</script>
```

I think my problem is in last 10 lines. I can send the URL_1 as href and share this link in my facebook post, but facebook does not redirect me to URL_2 after I share the post.

Thanks

Comment: why would you want to redirect after sharing? what´s the point? maybe the user wants to use the share function twice, to share it on different channels?

Comment: btw, did you try with "display: 'page'"?